# JavaScript: How to change an element property from argument?

Tags: javascript, properties

Imagine simple JS script:

```
function change_color(id, property, color){
   document.getElementById(id).style.[NEED TO USE property HERE] = color;
}

change_color('div', 'backgroundColor', '#333333');
```

I need to use one function to change backgroundColor, color (font), borderColor or any other color property of element. The property should be defined as an attribute of a function.

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: The dot is wrong in this place. `foo.bar` == `foo['bar']` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function change_color(id, prop, color){
    document.getElementById(id).style[prop] = color;
}
```

But you should better use jQuery, because then you know your code is working in every browser.